# Googles Sankey Diagram with csv data

Tags: javascript, csv, sankey-diagram

I want to get csv data via a file into below sankey diagram:

I use this code from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey

```
<html>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="sankey_multiple" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["sankey"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'From');
    data.addColumn('string', 'To');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
    data.addRows([
       [ 'Brazil', 'Portugal', 5 ],
       [ 'Brazil', 'France', 1 ],
       [ 'Brazil', 'Spain', 1 ],
       [ 'Brazil', 'England', 1 ],
       [ 'Canada', 'Portugal', 1 ],
       [ 'Canada', 'France', 5 ],
       [ 'Canada', 'England', 1 ],
       [ 'Mexico', 'Portugal', 1 ],
       [ 'Mexico', 'France', 1 ],
       [ 'Mexico', 'Spain', 5 ],
       [ 'Mexico', 'England', 1 ],
       [ 'USA', 'Portugal', 1 ],
       [ 'USA', 'France', 1 ],
       [ 'USA', 'Spain', 1 ],
       [ 'USA', 'England', 5 ],
       [ 'Portugal', 'Angola', 2 ],
       [ 'Portugal', 'Senegal', 1 ],
       [ 'Portugal', 'Morocco', 1 ],
       [ 'Portugal', 'South Africa', 3 ],
       [ 'France', 'Angola', 1 ],
       [ 'France', 'Senegal', 3 ],
       [ 'France', 'Mali', 3 ],
       [ 'France', 'Morocco', 3 ],
       [ 'France', 'South Africa', 1 ],
       [ 'Spain', 'Senegal', 1 ],
       [ 'Spain', 'Morocco', 3 ],
       [ 'Spain', 'South Africa', 1 ],
       [ 'England', 'Angola', 1 ],
       [ 'England', 'Senegal', 1 ],
       [ 'England', 'Morocco', 2 ],
       [ 'England', 'South Africa', 7 ],
       [ 'South Africa', 'China', 5 ],
       [ 'South Africa', 'India', 1 ],
       [ 'South Africa', 'Japan', 3 ],
       [ 'Angola', 'China', 5 ],
       [ 'Angola', 'India', 1 ],
       [ 'Angola', 'Japan', 3 ],
       [ 'Senegal', 'China', 5 ],
       [ 'Senegal', 'India', 1 ],
       [ 'Senegal', 'Japan', 3 ],
       [ 'Mali', 'China', 5 ],
       [ 'Mali', 'India', 1 ],
       [ 'Mali', 'Japan', 3 ],
       [ 'Morocco', 'China', 5 ],
       [ 'Morocco', 'India', 1 ],
       [ 'Morocco', 'Japan', 3 ]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
      width: 600,
    };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_multiple'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is import a csv file with 3 variables into this Sankey chart, instead of hardcoding it as done here.

Example of the CSV file could be:

From, to, count

google.com, amazon.com, 5

google.com, ford.com, 10

Table form if it is less confusing:

```
From              To     count
google.com  amazon.com     5
google.com  ford.com       10
```

Comment: Could you add the csv or give a small sample of it's structure?

Comment: have uploaded a example of the structure

Comment: Check this out - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_javadocs/com/google/visualization/datasource/util/CsvDataSourceHelper

Answer (score 1):

Google charts doesn't support loading CSV file out-of-the-box but you can use CSV plugin to convert it to an array .I would suggest using this one [jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv).Use it like this

```
<body>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="sankey_multiple" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["sankey"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    $.get("data.csv", function(csvString) {
      // fetch CSV file using ajax
      var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
      // after parsing , arrayData is 2-D array holding all the data contained in CSV file

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'From');
        data.addColumn('string', 'To');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
        data.addRows(arrayData);

      // Set chart options
      var options = {
        width: 600,
      };

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_multiple'));
      chart.draw(data, options);

    });
  }

</script>
</body>
```

Your data.csv file may look like this , no need of headers

```
google.com,amazon.com,5
google.com,ford.com,10
google.com,stackoverflow.com,50
google.com,ford.com,10
```